# Run a bash command and SQL query from javascript button

Tags: php, mysql, bash

Need to run a bash command and a SQL query from javascript

This is an ubuntu 18.04 server running apache2 and PHP 7.2.15 with a MySQL database. I need to append a text file with an IP address that is selected on our website and add the selected IP address to a table in our database. Below is the code for the javascript button and below that is the commands I need to run.

```
<button type="button" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnConfirm" data-dismiss="modal">Save changes</button>
```

```
sudo echo 'IP ADDRESS' >> /etc/snort/rules/iplists/whitelist.rules && INSERT INTO `whitelist` (`ip_address`) VALUES (INET_ATON("<variable for IP>"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a client-side language. That means all of it runs outside of your server. To do what you want, you need to create an entry point in your sever to let it know when clients want to run the sql query and the bash command and then do it. This can be done vía a RESTful service.

Simply put:

Client wants to run something in server → RESTful service receives request → Server handles the request (this is when you run the bash command and the SQL query) → Server returns a response through the same RESTful service

Comment: Yea that makes sense. I'm not a web developer by any means so this is new to me. I'll try your suggestion.